# How to get rid of BOM (byte order mark)

Tags: character-encoding

How can I open a file with a BOM Byte Order Mark and ensure that BOM is gone when I save the file.

Comment: Do you want this for *all* encodings? Or just, say, utf-8 ?

Comment: Quick answer here: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/emacs-byte-order-marks.html

Answer (score 7):

Check out the file encoding with <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>. If there is a byte order mark in the file, you may see something like this in the `*Help*` buffer:

```
Coding system for saving this buffer:
  U -- utf-8-with-signature-unix
```

Instead of `-unix`, it might say `-dos` or `-mac`, and possibly it might start with some variant of `utf-16` instead of `utf-8`.

If you don't want the byte order mark, just switch to the corresponding encoding *without* the `-with-signature` part. Use <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-m</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> (`set-buffer-file-coding-system`) to achieve this.

(Disclaimer: I don't know for how long the `-with-signature` UTF encodings have been part of emacs. If you run an old emacs, this may not work for you.)

Comment: I got so irritated about the apparent need for `find-file-literally` (see the other answer by me), I decided to dig harder, and found this. Now I am happier. Hope it will be useful to others. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864979/1842907).

Comment: Sanity check: if emacs tells you that `RET runs the command newline` when you check the file encoding, be sure you used a *capital* C in your `C-h C RET`.

Answer (score 4):

`M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system`, hit TAB to get a completion list, select encoding you desire (one without BOM), then save the file.

Answer (score 2):

A comment by SabreWolfy really should be provided as an answer: As explained in [a blog post](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/emacs-byte-order-marks.html) by Bojan Nikolic, the BOM (which really is the Unicode character U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE placed at the beginning of a file) is sometimes used to indicate the file encoding (and byte order, in the case of UTF-16). When emacs opens a file with a BOM, it will not show it as part of the buffer, so you can't get rid of it.

The remedy is to visit the file with `M-x find-file-literally`. If the encoding was UTF-8, the BOM will show up at the beginning of the file as three binary characters: `\357\273\277` (they may look like twelve characters, but there really are only three). Delete those three characters, then save the file.

Comment: Community wiki because I really can't claim any credit for this answer. I don't know if any non-Unicode encodings use BOMs too? If they do, feel free to edit the answer to reflect that.